# Symfony build all, but don't delete records

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I was just curious if there was a way to issue the following command, but not have it delete all the records:

```
php symfony doctrine:build --all
```

The reason I'm asking is because the symfony project would be using an existing database, which has a lot of records already. The usage of that command would totally clear it out and recreate the tables, minus the data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the separate build commands that you need one by one, instead of using build --all

Build --all is equivalent to running the following tasks:

```
./symfony doctrine:drop-db
./symfony doctrine:build-db
./symfony doctrine:build-model
./symfony doctrine:build-forms
./symfony doctrine:build-filters
./symfony doctrine:build-sql
./symfony doctrine:insert-sql
```

Obviously, you don't want to run the first two.
If you don't like running all of these commands manually, you can create a batch script to execute what you need.

If you did make changes to your schema, then you will need to create migration classes to generate the differences.  Take a look at the following, if you need to do this:
[Migration Task](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks#chapter_16_sub_doctrine_generate_migration)

Comment: If you're changing the database outside of the config files via phpmyadmin or another direct method, make sure to rebuild your schema before the model as well. ./symfony doctrine:build-schema